# D3 - y axis not being appended to chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following [this tutorial](http://jonsadka.com/blog/how-to-create-live-updating-and-flexible-d3-line-charts-using-pseudo-data/), and have run into an issue with displaying the y axis for my chart, which I think it preventing my data from appearing as well. Here is a fiddle with some dummy data that I'm plotting for the time being:

https://jsfiddle.net/katiebroida/1vonf6v8/8/

As you'll see in the fiddle when inspecting the elements in the results, the x axis is appended to the chart div, in addition to path elements for the line representing data. However, the y axis doesn't seem to be appended at all.

Here is the code itself:

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="stockChart"></div>
  <script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v2.js'></script>
</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var stockData = [
  {date: 1,lastPrice: 54},
  {date: 2,lastPrice: 78},
  {date: 3,lastPrice: 32},
  {date: 4,lastPrice: 44},
  {date: 5,lastPrice: 11},
];
  var width = 550;
  var height = 200;
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50};

  // draw and append the container
  var svg = d3.select('#stockChart').append('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append('g')
      .attr('transform','translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.right + ')');

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);

  var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d){ return xScale(d.date); })
    .y(function(d){ return yScale(d.lastPrice); });


  function drawLineChart(){

    // obtain absolute min and max
    var yMin = stockData.reduce(function(pv,cv){
      return Math.min(pv, cv.lastPrice);
    },100);

    var yMax = stockData.reduce(function(pv,cv){
      return Math.max(pv,cv.lastPrice);
    },0);

    var xMin = stockData.reduce(function(pv, cv){
      return Math.min(pv, cv.date);
    }, 100);

    var xMax = stockData.reduce(function(pv, cv){
      return Math.max(pv, cv.date);
    }, 0);

    // create domains for axis
    yScale.domain([yMin, yMax]);
    xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);

    // create axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom');
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');

    // if no axis exists, create one, otherwise update it
    if (svg.selectAll('.y.axis')[0].length < 1 ){
      svg.append('g')
          .attr('class','y axis')
          .call(yAxis);
    } else {
      svg.selectAll('.y.axis').transition().duration(1500).call(yAxis);
    }

    if (svg.selectAll('.x.axis')[0].length < 1 ){
      svg.append('g')
          .attr('class','x axis')
          .call(xAxis);
    } else {
      svg.selectAll('.x.axis').transition().duration(1500).call(xAxis);
    }

    // remove previously existing lines, if any
    svg.selectAll('.y.axis').remove();

    var lines = svg.selectAll('.line').data(stockData).attr('class', 'line');

    lines.enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', line).style('stroke', 'blue');
  }

  drawLineChart();
```

Is there something I'm missing for why the y axis isn't being appended to the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
svg.selectAll('.y.axis').remove();
```

Is removing the axis, comment this out.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/1vonf6v8/9/

The dummy data doesnt show however. So I changed your line create function to this :

```
  var lines = svg.append("path")
    .datum(stockData)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Added this piece of CSS :

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

And now plots fine. Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/1vonf6v8/11/

Comment: Looks like you want this in when adding new data maybe ? Even though this may not be the correct way to go, I would put that line at the beginning of the function if you wish to use it :)